# md5 encryption decryption

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a field in my database table with the name download_key. It is saved normally in the table no encryption is done. I am sending this key as hidden value in the form. If someone right click on the page and view the source of page the key is visible. Is it possible to encrypt it in the view only? I am also comparing the hidden value of the key with the one stored in database.

Some code

Controller

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
$row = $query->row();
$data['download_key'] = strtolower($row->downloadkey);
```

Inside my view

```
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm('<?php echo $download_key ?>')"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $download_key ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: There is Encryption Class available - have you looked? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: Why do you need to show the key to the user anyway if it isn't meant to be seen by the user?

Comment: @HappyApe Can you please answer this question your solution worked for me

Comment: @HappyApe How can I do SHA1 encoding using javascript because I am encrypting it using sha1 method and I have to compare it to the user provided key. How can i encrypt the user input in javascript

Comment: mmm... tried this -> var myJsKey = "<?php echo sha1("string"); ?>" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Encryption/Decryption functions available - please have a look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

```
$msg = 'My secret message';
$key = 'super-secret-key';

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($msg, $key);

$encrypted_string = 'APANtByIGI1BpVXZTJgcsAG8GZl8pdwwa84';

$plaintext_string = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_string);
```

See if this helps in your case. :)

Comment: How can I do SHA1 encryption using javascript because I am encrypting it using sha1 method and I have to compare it to the user provided key. How can i encrypt the user input in javascript

Comment: The encoding is different :( I use $data['download_key']= $this->encrypt->sha1($download_key); in my controller, then I send this download key as hidden field this encoding gives the value 89b70feb65992e6156f9ec9b4bbf658d49c9aeb8 and the one I use in javascript  var input_key = <?php echo sha1(key); ?> gives other value

Comment: I am not sure how you are passing and validating ----- but maybe you don't need to encode the key again in JS - for example, $data['download_key'] = 'your-key-without-encryption'; $data['encrypted_download_key'] = sha1($data['download_key']); , then in JS just use var myJSKey = "<?php echo $encrypted_download_key; ?>";

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use sessions?

```
$_SESSION['DL_KEY'] = strtolower($row->downloadkey);
```

and there will not be necessarry to echo it in the form

Answer (score 1):

Try using reversable encryption with key (that will be only in your config, hidden from anyone else).

```
$key = 'YOUR_UNIQUE_KEY_HERE';
$phrase = 'PHRASE_TO_DECODE_OR_ENCODE';
if ($method == 'encode')
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $phrase, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND)));
else if ($method == 'decode')
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($phrase), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at function [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php). It is a native php function. Has nothing to do with codeigniter.

`string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )` is the function signature.

Comment: there is no decryption for md5().

Answer (score 0):

Print your key in the form like this:

```
    echo $this->encrypt->encode($download_key);
```

Then, before it gets inserted into the database, do this:

```
    $download_key = $this->encypt->decode($download_key);
```